# Karate: passing dynamic parameter values via the command line not working

Tags: javascript, karate

I am trying to pass a URL from the command line when I run karate integration tests on the command line. I took a look at [this](https://github.com/intuit/karate#dynamic-port-numbers) and tried to do the same thing but so far no luck.

I have this `karate-config.js` file

```
function karateconf() {
  karate.configure('connectTimeout', 5000);
  karate.configure('readTimeout', 5000);
  var config = { baseURL: 'http://localhost:8080' };

  if (karate.env == 'ci') {
    config.baseURL = karate.properties['base.URL'];
    karate.log('*******************************', karate.properties['base.URL']);
  }

  return config;
}
```

And I run the test using gradle like this

```
./gradlew integrationTest -Dkarate.env=ci  -Dbase.URL=http://someurl:8080
```

And here is the karate logs

```
14:12:54.599 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  com.intuit.karate - ******************************* null 
14:12:54.827 [pool-1-thread-1] ERROR com.intuit.karate - url not set, please refer to the keyword documentation for 'url'
14:12:54.827 [pool-1-thread-1] ERROR com.intuit.karate - http request failed: url not set, please refer to the keyword documentation for 'url'
14:12:54.836 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  c.i.karate.cucumber.CucumberRunner - <<<< feature 1 of 1 on thread pool-1-thread-1: com/guidewire/lifecycle/controller/configuration-controller.feature
14:12:55.359 [Test worker] INFO  n.m.cucumber.ReportParser - File '/workspace/configuration-service/configuration-infrastructure/app-backend/lifecycle/target/surefire-reports/TEST-com.guidewire.lifecycle.controller.configuration-controller.json' contain 1 features
```

I could not figure out what I am missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gradle ? This is covered in the documentation: https://github.com/intuit/karate#command-line - and looks like you need to add `base.URL` to your gradle build file the same way as below:

> For gradle you must extend the test task to allow the cucumber.options
>   to be passed to the Cucumber-JVM (otherwise they get consumed by
>   gradle itself). To do that, add the following:

```
test {
    // pull cucumber options into the cucumber jvm
    systemProperty "cucumber.options", System.properties.getProperty("cucumber.options")
    // pull karate options into the jvm
    systemProperty "karate.env", System.properties.getProperty("karate.env")
    // ensure tests are always run
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
}
```